# Output automorphic numbers in C

Tags: c

I need to output 10 automorphic numbers ,5 in each row.
I wrote below code, but it doesn't work correct, can you help me please?
Automorphic numbers which i need to output : "1, 5, 6, 25, 76,
376, 625, 9376, 90625, 109376".

```
int n = 10, m = 10, a, b, c;
for ( n = 1; n < 11; n++) {
b = m;
while (n > b) {
    b = b * m;
}
a = (n * n) % b;
if (a == n)
{
    printf("%d ", n);
    if (n % 6 == 0)
        printf("\n");

}
a++;
```

Comment: What's an automorphic number? What output do you get? Where are your #includes? Where is `main`?

Comment: The last two terms do not fit a 32-bit `int` when squared.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the square of the number ends with the same number. For example 25 * 25 = 625 so its an automorphic number.

Comment: Trying to use `n` as both a counter for the number of required outputs and as the number under test for automorphism seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @WeatherVanethanks, but it's the OP's job to put this information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem.

Here's what I came up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int i=1;
    while(counter < 10)
    {
        if (i*i % (int)pow(10,(int)log10(i)+1) == i)
        {
            counter++;
            printf("%d) %d is automorphic because %d * %d == %d\n", counter, i, i, i, i*i);
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4516KB
1) 1 is automorphic because 1 * 1 == 1
2) 5 is automorphic because 5 * 5 == 25
3) 6 is automorphic because 6 * 6 == 36
4) 25 is automorphic because 25 * 25 == 625
5) 76 is automorphic because 76 * 76 == 5776
6) 376 is automorphic because 376 * 376 == 141376
7) 625 is automorphic because 625 * 625 == 390625
8) 9376 is automorphic because 9376 * 9376 == 87909376
```

(I stopped after finding 8 values due to time-constraints)

Comment: Interesting. One optimisation is that the number can only end with a 0, 1, 5, or 6.  If the last 2 digits are considered, only numbers ending in 00, 01, 25 and 76 need to be tested.